# Express + Multer + Google Cloud Storage Error: "Requires a callback function"

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-storage, multer

I am trying to do the following in an Express route:

```
const multer = Multer({
storage: Multer.MemoryStorage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024 // Maximum file size is 10MB
  }
});

const gcsMiddlewares = require("../common/google-cloud-storage");

router.post(
  "/",
  multer.single("image"),
  gcsMiddlewares.sendUploadToGCS,
  (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.file && req.file.gcsUrl) {
    return res.send(req.file.gcsUrl);
    }

    return res.status(500).send("Unable to upload");
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

and I am getting the following error:

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Please elucidate, if you have any idea what is happening exactly.

Comment: Check you `sendUploadToGCS`, please be ensured that this is returning `function`.

Comment: @Tokenyet my path should have been `const gcsMiddlewares = require("../middlewears/google-cloud-storage");` error is gone now that I am importing function correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Glad everything worked out. @Tokenyet Could you post what you said as an answer to make it more visible to the community and so that we may upvote it?

Comment: I got It, I didn't expect this issue is sloved by my comment :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is happened, because **express**'s [middleware](https://expressjs.com/zh-tw/guide/using-middleware.html) chain need a function.
ex.
`(req, res, next) => {}`

Although the solution is short, I'll make an answer to let others know this is sloved.